# Sum of the first and last array elements in Java

Tags: java

I'm using JB IntelliJ IDEA and trying to create a program which finds the sum of the first and last elements of a randomly generated array using the `sum()` method. My problem is that an error occures, please help me.

Here is my code:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {
    public static int sum(int[] array) {
        int x = array[0];
        int y = array[9];
        int z = x + y;
        return z;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int j = rand.nextInt(50);
            System.out.println(sum());
        }
    }
}
```

and error:

> Error:(15, 32) java: method sum in class com.company.Main cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: int[]
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Method `sum()` should have an input as an integer array since the method signature is like this `public static int sum(int[] array)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**
**Error:(15, 32) java: method sum in class com.company.Main cannot be applied to given types;**

**required: int[]**

**found: no arguments**

**reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length**

Going through the Error itself says everything about the issue:

**required: int[]**

**found: no arguments**

It is saying that it required an array of data type int which is missing(no arguments) and that is why **actual and formal argument lists differ in length**

Hence, Sum function requires an array to be passed as a parameter.

Also, you are getting random integer value in a integer variable **j = rand.nextInt(50);** but not assigning it to the array which is just wasting the loop to run unnecessarily 10 times.

Instead of assigning it to j we can directly assign it to the array and fill array with the random integers before passing it to the method **sum(array)**:

Try this updated code with the changes needed:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {
    public static int sum(int[] array) {
        int x = array[0];
        int y = array[9];
        int z = x + y;
        return z;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = rand.nextInt(50);
        }
        System.out.println(sum(array));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass the array to the method. Change your line

```
System.out.println(sum());
```

to

```
System.out.println(sum(array));
```

Also you did not put `j` into `array` and you call sum before `array` is filled.

Answer (score 0):

You method sum requires an attribute of the type int[]. But in the statement System.out.println(sum()); you are not passing an attribute to your method.

Try out this code:

```
    public static int sum(int[] array) {
        int x = array[0];
        int y = array[9];
        int z = x + y;
        return z;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = rand.nextInt(50);
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(sum(array));
    }
```

Comment: It compiles, but array filled with zeros

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `array` with the `random()`, and then put the `array` as an argument to call `sum()` function.
The codes as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[10];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int j = rand.nextInt(50);
        array[i] = j;
    }
    System.out.println(sum(array));
}
```

And then, you can get the result that you want.